# DataSnapshot Firebase: Getvalue return null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to read the user's data from Firebase Realtime Database but it always returns null. Here is my code:

```
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();
    ref.child("shop").child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Users user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w("1abc", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

Here is the Users class:

```
public class Users {

    private String full_name;
    private String UID;
    private String email;

    public Users(String newemail, String newUID, String newfull_name) {
        // ...
        this.email=newemail;
        this.full_name=newfull_name;
        this.UID=newUID;
    }
    public Users() {
        // ...

    }
}
```

And here is my database tree:
[image]

Can someone tell me where am i wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: check value of `mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()`

Comment: @kdblue There is no error, just not run correctly

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh: it's normal :(

Comment: is it the same as the one in your db, can you post it

Comment: make Users model members public !

Comment: @kdblue OMG you are a life saver. Thank you

Comment: @Dang Tam accept my answer it will help others ! Thank You .

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

make Users model members public !

```
public class Users {

        public String full_name;
        public String UID;
        public String email;

        public Users(String newemail, String newUID, String newfull_name) {
            // ...
            this.email=newemail;
            this.full_name=newfull_name;
            this.UID=newUID;
        }
        public Users() {
            // ...

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add getters and setters in your POJO class:

```
public class Users {

private String full_name;
private String UID;
private String email;


public Users(String newemail, String newUID, String newfull_name) {
    // ...
    this.email=newemail;
    this.full_name=newfull_name;
    this.UID=newUID;
}
public Users() {
    // ...

}

public String getFull_name() {
  return full_name;
 }

 public void setFull_name(String full_name) {
   this.full_name = full_name;
 }

 public String getUID() {
    return UID;
  }

 public void setUID(String UID) {
    this.UID = UID;
  }

 public String getEmail() {
  return email;
 } 

 public void setEmail(String email) {
   this.email = email;
   }
}
```